# SQL Group by Count of Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I'm combining two tables with an inner join where the Primary ID is the movie ID, and I'd like to group them by number of movies per actor per year. However - possibly because the movie ID is the primary key - the results that I'm getting aren't correct. Below is my code. The DB is from iMDB, it has a cast table with movies and actors, an actors table and a movies table with the year.

```
SELECT 
                c.actor_id, m.year, COUNT(m.title)
            FROM
                cast c
            INNER JOIN movies m
            WHERE
                c.movie_id = m.id
            GROUP BY m.year
            ORDER BY COUNT(m.title) DESC;
```

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to include `actor_id` in the `GROUP` clause cause you are counting number of movies per actor per year.

```
SELECT 
                c.actor_id, m.year, COUNT(m.title)
            FROM
                cast c
            INNER JOIN movies m
            WHERE
                c.movie_id = m.id
            GROUP BY c.actor_id, m.year
            ORDER BY COUNT(m.title) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything not aggregated must be in `GROUP BY`. Most RDBMSs would error out on your SQL, but MySQL would give you "a free pass" on it:

```
SELECT 
    c.actor_id, m.year, COUNT(m.title)
FROM
    cast c
INNER JOIN actor_movie am ON am.actor_id=am.actor_id
INNER JOIN movies m ON am.movie_id=m.movie_id
WHERE
    c.movie_id = m.id
GROUP BY c.actor_id, m.year
ORDER BY COUNT(m.title) DESC;
```

Note that inner join needs an `ON` clause which you did not include. I added one possible implementation with an actor-movie table that I suppose you have (or should have).

Comment: Whether or not the DB allows it, if he wants the counts to be per-actor, it needs to be in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Barmar I was trying to make a point that other DBs would probably stop OP in his tracks by pointing out the need to use actor_id in the group by.